# Rails 3 response mimetype and content-type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mime-types

Here is the trick. I have a model called Pages with a field called "page_type" wich can be one of, lets say, 3 variants: "html", "image", "vcard", and a field called "content".
So now I need the app to respond with different mimetypes depending on what type of a page is requested.

If the page_type is set to "html" - render the content as html using the appropriate view and html_safe, that's easy.

If the page_type is set to "image" - get the image, using the path, stored in the content and send it back to the user as if he requested an image.

Same for "vcard".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're generating the URLs to access your resources (Page) in your app, you can specify the resource location RESTfully, such as /pages/2.jpg, /pages/3.vcard, /pages/4 (default is html) using the built-in Rails view helpers such as page_url(@page, :format => 'jpg').  Then it's simply a matter of using repond_to in Rails to deliver the resource:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { # default rendering in show.erb.html }
  format.jpg { # perhaps send_file or send_data call }
  format.vcard { # send attachment }
end
```

Check out the [Rails Routing Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more info. You'll need to configure Rails to handle requests for .vcard. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1333501).

If you don't control link generation (external references to your resources) and expect to get requests like /pages/2 (which is a jpeg), then you'll have to fall back to using your page_type column to conditionally render with send_file, send_data, or other Rails rendering methods. You might consider re-using the logic (methods) you create for each block in respond_to above, so that your controller has 'respond_to_html', 'respond_to_jpg', 'respond_to_vcard' methods.